# How to decode %21 with ! symbol in the query param of the URL in swagger editor

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I have a rest URL and i am trying to hit the URL using the swagger editor online.In the URL there is query param "....../Location_Address?Location%21ID=92b913cbeafb1000136edb3ea6df1349!6ec4cb72635310000ea06db19466001c"
In the query param name "%21" is used, it should ideally decode %21 to "!".But it is converting as "%2521". It means it decoded "%" symbol with "%25".
I want to make the Query param look like this
Location!ID=92b913cbeafb1000136edb3ea6df1349!6ec4cb72635310000ea06db19466001c"

Please help?

my swagger for query param looks like this
`"parameters": [ { "name": "Location%21ID", "in": "query", "description": "PassID", "required": false, "type": "string" } ],`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
"name": "Location%21ID"
```

with

```
"name": "Location!ID"
```